# Pausing a game loop?

Tags: java, clock

So I have this piece of code, setting dt in a game loop (`clock` is of type `Clock`):

```
    // set delta time
    float currentTime = clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
    float dt = currentTime - lastTime;
    // ...
    lastTime = currentTime;
```

However, when the game is paused, the clock still runs. So as the game is paused, dt becomes large. How would I avoid this?

Comment: Is `Clock` your own type?

Comment: You will need to track when the game is paused and unpaused and factor that into your `currentTime-lastTime` calculation.

Comment: `Clock` is an object from JSFML. Also, how would I do that? @MattCoubrough

Comment: Think he means you need to set a check like a boolean when your game is paused or not then do a simple IF statement to see if it is NOT paused then continue to add time

Comment: I can't stop the clock.

Comment: `dt = currentTime - lastTime` is simply performing maths. If game is paused don't do this! But *do* set lastTime to currentTime. Think about it.

Comment: But the `currentTime` will still be the time that accumulated during the pause, so that won't work.

Comment: `currentTime` is not the accumulated time during the pause, it is the current time. If `lastTime` is set to currentTime on every update, but dt is set to 0 while the game is paused then there is no delta (accumulated time) during the pause. Hopefully someone will explain it to you better than I can.

Comment: The clock gets the current time, which is much more than the last frame's time if the game was paused.

Comment: Yes, the internal clock will keep on running. You will have to keep a *delta* time variable: the time spent "in paused". Subtract that from the clock time to get the game time.

Comment: you could just call `clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();` when you unpause the game to reset it to zero?

Answer (score 0):

A possible, basilar approach could be something like the following one (pseudocode):

```
var elapsed = current - previous;
if(elapsed > clampOverElapsed) {
    elapsed = clampOverElapsed;
}
```

Where `clampOverElapsed` is set somewhere to a reasonable value, as an example 25 ms.
This way, by having that control within the loop, you should nicely handle pauses as well as unseasonably longer iterations, without caring about what's the source of your big `elapsed` value, so that you have not to explicit